# 'Publish' button in Google Spreadsheets to make HTTP Request to Heroku

Tags: git, heroku, web, google-apps-script

I'm a newbie in web engineering. I'm trying to build a project that whenever my google spreadsheet file updates, my github repository will update the file as well. It works like this:

1) Google spreadsheet creates/updates the file

2) I click "Publish on the web" button

3) Button makes HTTP request to my Heroku app

4) Heroku commits a CSV file containing google spreadsheet contents

5) Github repo is updated

My question is, how do I do steps 2, 3, and 4? How do I make the clicking of the "Publish on the web" button in Google spreadsheet make an HTTP request to my heroku, to get contents and make it into CSV variables? Thanks!

Comment: In general the idea of Heroku performing a Git commit doesn't make much sense. Unless your application itself handles the commit (e.g. through [`dulwich`](https://github.com/jelmer/dulwich) or [Rugged](https://github.com/libgit2/rugged) or similar) you are probably on the wrong track. What is your actual goal?

Answer (score 0):

Short and incomplete answer (I dont' know how Heroku works):

2) You can make a custom menu or a clickable image on your sheet to start your script.

3) You can use UrlFetchApp like

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.google.com/");
```

to request samething to your url.

4) The getDataRange() example shows how to get the sheet content in CSV format:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange